# scaling Azure Application Gateway while it's running?

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I wonder - is it possible to change size of Azure Application Gateway after it's started without interrupting it's work? I am hoping for changing it based on the utilization of nodes and the traffic going up/down.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information provided in the answer by Lech Migdal on Oct 31 2016 is no longer valid. According to the FAQ it is possible to scale Application Gateway and change size without service interruption:

> Q. Can I change instance size from medium to large without disruption?
>
> Yes, Azure distributes instances across update and fault domains to
>   ensure that all instances do not fail at the same time. Application
>   Gateway supports scaling by adding multiple instances of the same
>   gateway to share the load.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq